# Does my add method correctly add a at a given position in my linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, insert, nodes

This class was written to create a Singly Linked List and has methods for creating a new node in a such a linked list.

```
package utilities;

public class SLLNode
{
    private Object element;
    private SLLNode successor;

    public SLLNode(Object o)
    {
        this.element = o;
    }

    public void setNext(SLLNode sllNode)
    {
        this.successor = sllNode;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public SLLNode getNext()
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return successor;
    }

    public Object getElement()
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return element;
    }

    //Constants
    //Attributes
    //Constructors
    //Getter and Setter Methods
    //Operational Methods
}
```

The following method is relating to the title of this question, it was written to add a new node to a specific position in a `SLL`. Does it make sense? Does this code iterate in the for loop to add a Node at the specified position?

I have been trying to figure this one out for a long time and I would really appreciate feedback. Thank you very much in advance.

```
@Override
public boolean add(Object element, int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
{
//While the head != null iterate to the position of the list and add a new node
    int i;
    if(head != null)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < position; i++)
        {
            head.getNext();
            if(i == position)
            {
                head.setNext(new SLLNode(element));
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    head = new SLLNode(element);

    return false;
}
```

I tried really hard to figure this out. I will keep trying. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

No you replace next element instead of shifting, your add method calls

```
public void setNext(SLLNode sllNode)
{
    this.successor = sllNode;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

So old successor and its siblings dissapeared here, if you check how its implemented in java:

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
        checkPositionIndex(index);

        if (index == size)
            linkLast(element);
        else
            linkBefore(element, node(index));
    }
```

probably interesting part here `linkBefore`:

```
void linkBefore(E e, Node<E> succ) {
        // assert succ != null;
        final Node<E> pred = succ.prev;
        final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(pred, e, succ);
        succ.prev = newNode;
        if (pred == null)
            first = newNode;
        else
            pred.next = newNode;
        size++;
        modCount++;
    }
```

Long story in short keep the old element in memory before then replacing then add your new element and attach the old node  to new added element using new.setNext(old). This way you will have the shifting

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the returned value by `getNext()` among others, use a temporary holder to store it. The code below provides one possible solution:

```
@Override
public boolean add(Object element, int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    int i;
    SLLNode holder = null;

    if (head != null) {
        for(i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            holder = head.getNext();
            if (i == position) {
                SLLNode node = new SLLNode(element);

                //save next before overwriting it
                SLLNode next = holder.getNext(); 

                //holder references the last accessed element
                holder.setNext(node);

                //link the new node to the next node
                //to avoid breaking the list
                node.setNext(next);

                return true;
            }
        }
    } else
        head = new SLLNode(element);

    return false;
}
```